# What makes conical coils that good in microwave circuits?

Tags: coil, microwave

Conical coils are often used in microwave technology.

**Can someone explain what makes this shape so unique?** How does this shape affect parasitic capacitances?

Some conical coil photos:

[image]

[image]

*This is NOT homework question. I'm just curious.*

Comment: Because it behaves like this model: https://www.coilcraft.com/images/Conical_Ad_Image.jpg

Comment: To help with what @user1999 added, you can view [this page](https://passive-components.eu/what-is-a-conical-inductor/) where you can also find this quote: "The conical shape limits the effects of stray capacitance and effectively creates a series of narrow band inductors, resulting in high impedance over a very wide bandwidth. A single conical inductor can replace a series of many narrow band inductors."

Comment: @jonk you should copy that comment into an answer.

Comment: @user1999, the conical inductor only provides the inductive part of that circuit.

Comment: @jonk I have converted your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Converting @jonk's comment into an answer:

> **The conical shape limits the effects of stray capacitance and
> effectively creates a series of narrow band inductors**, resulting in
> high impedance over a very wide bandwidth. A single conical inductor
> can replace a series of many narrow band inductors. ([source](https://passive-components.eu/what-is-a-conical-inductor/))

For more information, refer to this [pdf](https://open.library.ubc.ca/media/download/pdf/24/1.0314321/4).

Answer (score 0):

take a look here,
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1418000
"Conical inductors for broadband applications"